# Stretch the gather environment individual

Tags: equations

In the lecture note, on I am working, we use lots of equations. To set them I use often the `gather` environment of the `amsmath` package. But how it standard looks, I don't really like. First of all, I have no influence to make the vertical space (before or after the equation) greater or less.
That's why I made a little change on the `gather` environment and named it `Gather`

I show how it works:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\mathe}
\mathe3pt
\newlength{\mathvariable}
\mathvariable3pt
\newlength{\foren}
\newcommand{\en}{\\[\foren]}        
\newcommand{\stretchtheequations}{0}

\newenvironment{Gather}[1][\stretchtheequations]{%
\setlength{\mathe}{#1\mathvariable}%
\setlength{\foren}{10.75pt+1.5\mathe}
\vskip-\parskip%
\vskip-\baselineskip%
\vskip\mathe% -24pt
  \start@gather\st@rredfalse%
}{%
  \math@cr \black@\totwidth@ \egroup%
  $$\ignorespacesafterend%
  \vskip-\parskip%
  \vskip\mathe% -24pt
}
\makeatother
```

It based on standard `gather` environment from the `amsmath` package.

It would be added the `setlength` and `vskip` commands, the rest is from the original.

The following minimal example helps me explaining what I want to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\parskip10pt

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}  
% include here the code above

\begin{document}

\blindtext\ -- equation is compressed
    \begin{Gather}[-2.5]
        a+b+c+d   \en
        a+b+c+d   \en
        a+b+c+d   
    \end{Gather}
\blindtext\ -- equation is stretched
    \begin{Gather}[3]
        a+b+c+d   \en
        a+b+c+d   \en
        a+b+c+d   
    \end{Gather}
\blindtext

\clearpage
Look, how it looks, with columnbreak inside the multicols environment:

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \blindtext
    \columnbreak
    \begin{gather}
        a+b+c+d
    \end{gather}
    \blindtext
    \\\bfseries The gather environment begins at the same height as the text at left side. That's exactly what I want with my new Gather environment.
\end{multicols}

\clearpage
Look, how it looks, with columnbreak inside the multicols environment:

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \blindtext
    \columnbreak
    \begin{Gather}
        a+b+c+d
    \end{Gather}
    \blindtext
    \\\bfseries The Gather environment begins NOT at the same height as the text at left side.
\end{multicols}

\cleartoverso
\blindtext

\clearpage
    \begin{Gather}
        a+b+c+d
    \end{Gather}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

On the first page, you can see, how stretching works.

Page 3 shows that if I take the `gather` environment inside `multicols`, the first line of the equation begins exactly at the same height as the text at left side.

On page 4 you can see, that with `Gather` it is not the case. 
It is the same, if I use the `Gather` environment after `\clearpage`(see pages 6 and 7).

**And now the question**

I would like to create an environment which works exactly like `Gather` now, with the exception, that there won't be added any vertical space before the equation if it is used immediately after commands `\clearpage`, `\pagebreak`, `\newpage`.

So the behaviour is the same like `gather` on page 3 inside the multicols environment and after `\columnbreak`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the setting of the length, but here's something that can help you:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Gather}[1][0]
  {\abovedisplayskip=2pt \belowdisplayskip=\abovedisplayskip
   \setlength{\mathe}{#1\mathvariable}%
   \setlength{\foren}{10.75pt+1.5\mathe}%
   \start@gather\st@rredfalse}
  {\math@cr \black@\totwidth@ \egroup
   $$\ignorespacesafterend}
\makeatother
```

You can act on `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` to set the distance from the text to the `Gather` environment's contents. This way no `\parskip` glue will be inserted.

Comment: I find this answer usefull, because I've learnt, how `abovedisplayskip` and `belowdisplayskip` works. I hope, I can use this learning in the future. But this solution doesn't handle the problem with the `\clearpage` command. What I wanted, is a solution, that causes no vertcial skip (no abovedisplayskip) above the math environment, if it begins a new page. Even, if I set `abovedisplayskip` to zero, there will be a vertical space with the length of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, of course: `\clearpage` ends the current paragraph and `Gather` starts another one. Indeed `\columnbreak` uses a different strategy that you can find useful: in order to break a page before a `Gather` environment say `\vadjust{\eject}`.